# Display a random number from 1-5000 every second without any click to trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the input field, i would like it to display a random number from 1-5000 every second without any click to trigger.Is it possible?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
  $('#text').text(number);
},
1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Indeed, it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `val()` instead of `text()` for inputs

`$('#text').val(number);`

Snippet:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
  $('#text').val(number);
},
1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text"/>
```

---

And also, if you want to have a random number between **1** and 5000. you should have `+1`. `Math.random()` starts on 0.

```
 var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1;
```

Comment: And one more thing may i ask if i want to generate qr code based on that random number. Can i do this  var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode");

$("#text").on("input", function () {
    qrcode.makeCode($(this).val());
}).input().focus();

Comment: That depends on the library you are using. You should check the library documentation for that one.

Comment: I did. Both work fine when work separately. But when put together, cant work.Is there any way i could trigger the qr code to be generated when the number shown on the input?